# How to call function only once?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I call the function only for once?

```
var myFunction = function () {
    alert("calling function only for once");
}
myFunction();//alert "calling function only for once"
myFunction();//should not alert // if I call multiple times this should not be called
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
var myFunction = function () {
    alert("calling function only for once");
    myFunction = function(){
        return false;
    }
}
myFunction();//alert "calling function only for once"
myFunction();//should not alert
```

Answer (score 2):

Store some goobal variable a flag when run the function and check that variable at the start of the function.

Answer (score 1):

set a flag, and call according to that flag:

```
var IsAlreadyCalled=false;
var myFunction = function () {
   if(!IsAlreadyCalled){
      alert("calling function only for once");
      IsAlreadyCalled = true;
   }
}
myFunction();//alert "calling function only for once"
myFunction();//should not alert
```

Answer (score 1):

In your very odd scenario , the easiest way is to set a boolean:

```
var run = true,
    myFunction = function(){
        if(run){
            alert('calling function only for once');
            run = false;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    };

myFunction(); // will run
myFunction(); // won't run
```

That way later on if you need to "reactivate" it you can just set the boolean back to true and call it again.

```
run = true;
myFunction(); // will run again
```

Answer (score 0):

Other suggestions of using a flag are fine, but I would build it as a function decorator, that you can apply to any function. You avoid global variables this way, and your code becomes more readable and reusable:

```
// Takes a function and returns a function
// that executes only once
function once(f) {
  var flag;
  return function() {
    if (!flag) {
      flag = true;
      return f.apply(this, arguments);
    }
  };
}

var fn = once(function() {
  console.log('logged!');
});

fn(); // logged!
fn();
fn();
```

**Demo:** http://jsbin.com/povu/1/edit